# Gem::DependencyError while installing xcodeproj

Tags: xcode, nativescript

I have issues installing xcodeproj via Terminal on Mac. My Xcode version is 8.3.3. While working through the advanced installing instructions on [nativescript.org](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-os-x), I tried running

```
sudo gem install xcodeproj
```

which gives me the following error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
>       Unable to resolve dependencies: xcodeproj requires CFPropertyList (~> 2.3.3), claide (< 2.0, >= 1.0.2), colored2 (~> 3.1), nanaimo (~> 0.2.3)

Any ideas what I can do to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody is having the same problem:

installing and using cntlm did it for me.

Comment: hi. same problem. can you tell me more how about using cntlm?